# Making sequence unique with removal records

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I'm working on a tool to detect all exact tandem repeats in a DNA/RNA sequence. Part of the algorithm requires finding Longest Common Extension (LCE) values, which although can be computed in constant time, in practice it is (usually) better to use a naive \$O(n^2)\$ solution. The problem is that DNA sequences can contain long contiguous sequences of N's (unknown base). This can completely destroy the performance of the algorithm as it doesn't play nice with the \$O(n^2)\$ LCE algorithm. Solution: collapse all stretches of N's into a single N, no other repeats are missed (other than N's).

The problem is that then the repeats reported by the algorithm are in respect to the modified sequence, so I need to record how many N's have been removed before that position in the original sequence to get the correct position.

More generally: The algorithm should take as input a sequence `sequence` and a character `c`, collapse all contiguous sub-sequences of `c` into a single `c` (in-place), and record how many `c`s have been removed up until the next non-`c` character past the last removed `c`.

Here is my current attempt at this algorithm:

```
#include <map>
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t
#include <algorithm> // std::adjacent_find, std::find_if_not, std::unique
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end, std::distance, std::next

template <typename SequenceType>
std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t> collapse(SequenceType& sequence, char c)
{
    std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t> result {};

    auto first = std::begin(sequence);
    auto last  = std::end(sequence);

    std::size_t position {}, num_removed {};

    while (first != last) {
        auto it1 = std::adjacent_find(first, last, [c] (char lhs, char rhs) { return lhs == c && lhs == rhs; });

        if (it1 == last) break;

        auto it2 = std::find_if_not(it1, last, [c] (char b) { return b == c; });

        position    += std::distance(first, it1);
        num_removed += std::distance(it1, it2) - 1;

        result.emplace(position, num_removed);

        first = it2;
    }

    if (!result.empty()) {
        sequence.erase(std::unique(std::next(std::begin(sequence), result.cbegin()->first), last,
                                   [c] (char lhs, char rhs) { return lhs == c && lhs == rhs; }), last);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way that would avoid having to potentially scan the entire sequence twice (note the last call to `std::unique`)?

Comment: Is the input sequence a `std::string` or is it really required that it be a generic sequence type? I ask because it's hard to predict the costs of container operations without knowing the actual container type.

Comment: @Edward Almost certainly a `std::string`. The main reason I've used a generic type is that I'd like to be able to support other `std::basic_string` types (e.g. with different allocators), or `std::vector<char>`. In any case, it's fair to assume the input will be contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this seems to be readable code.  I would just note a few possible improvements:

### Use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::map`

The `std::map` may be appropriate if you plan on doing frequent lookups of the key values, but a `std::vector` might be a less expensive storage mechanism than `std::map` otherwise.

### Prefer `for` to `while` loop

The `while` loop may be more intuitively written as a `for` loop, as shown in the code below the next suggestion.

### Consolidate loops

As you've asked in your question, yes, the separate loop can be eliminated.  Once the pair of iterators (`it1` and `it2`) are found, simply use `erase` with those as parameters:

```
template <typename SequenceType>
std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t> collapse(SequenceType& sequence, char c)
{
    std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t> result {};

    std::size_t position {}, num_removed {};
    auto last = std::end(sequence);

    for(auto first = std::begin(sequence); first != last; last = std::end(sequence) ) {
        auto it1 = std::adjacent_find(first, last, [c] (char lhs, char rhs) { return lhs == c && lhs == rhs; });

        if (it1 == last) break;

        auto it2 = std::find_if_not(it1, last, [c] (char b) { return b == c; });

        position    += std::distance(first, it1);
        num_removed += std::distance(++it1, it2);

        result.emplace(position, num_removed);
        first = sequence.erase(it1, it2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Because `std::erase` returns an iterator following the last erased value, this also provides a handy way to update `first`.  Also, by incrementing `it1` within the `num_removed` update, we eliminate the need to subtract one and automatically correct the first iterator so that we eliminate only duplicate `N`s and not all of them.

### Consider the use of `std::regex`

It occurs to me that rather than use `compress` at all, perhaps `std::regex` might be better suited to solving this particular problem by eliminating the need to do preprocessing at all.  That is, with the proper regex, the notion of "one or more N's" is very quickly and easily represented.  Naturally, this assumes a more restrictive possibility range than a generic sequence object, but if your sequences are already `std::string` types, this may work very well.

Comment: I wonder what's more performant, calling `std::vector::erase` multiple times, or doing a double pass with a single `erase`...

Comment: Timing tests with representative data on your machine are likely to be the easiest and best way of answering that question.